# How to theme a link in a D7 render array?

Tags: theming

I'm trying this:

> ```
>         $content[] = array(
>           '#theme' => 'link',
>           '#text' => $row->title,
>           '#path' => $base_path . 'node/' . $row->nid,
>           '#attributes' => array('attributes' => array('title' => $row->title)),
>           '#prefix' => '<h3>',
>           '#suffix' => '</h3>',
>         );
> ```

but Drupal is complaining that "Arg 1 passed to drupal_attributes() must be an array, null given" My array looks fine? ...or does it xD

Here is the [API doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) I'm looking at

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `theme_link()` function behaves a bit like the `l()` function; the attributes array needs to be inside an `#options` property:

```
$link = array(
  '#theme' => 'link',
  '#text' => $row->title,
  '#path' => $base_path . 'node/' . $row->nid,
  '#options' => array('attributes' => array('title' => $row->title)),
  '#prefix' => '<h3>',
  '#suffix' => '</h3>'
);

echo render($link);
```

Comment: Who's awesome? Clive is awesome!

Comment: Crap, I was even on that page & didn't see that [comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_link/7#comment-12939), thanks for your attention to detail!

Comment: @Merrick No probs, I've been stung by this one before myself :)

Comment: [Apparently](http://drupal.org/node/1187032#comment-4711898) it's better to use `'#type' => 'link'` as otherwise some `l()` preprocessing gets missed. Note [the keys differ](http://drupal.org/node/1187032#comment-5534700) depending on the method.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to edit Clive post, but got rejected :(

---

As [Andy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-theme-a-link-in-a-d7-render-array/#comment76070_24698) pointed out, it's not recommended to use theme_link instead of l().
Using [`drupal_pre_render_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_link/7) is cleaner for renderable array.

```
 $link = array(
  '#type'  => 'link',
  '#title' => $row->title,
  '#href'  => 'node/' . $row->nid,
);
```

You can also go for the "easy-quick-fix" solution with #markup (But don't)

```
$link = array(
  '#markup' => l($row->title, 'node/' . $row->nid),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should read

```
'#attributes' => array('title' => $row->title),
```

The wording of the doc in [common.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) seems a little unclear, but see the doc for [drupal_attributes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_attributes/7) for an example.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that first and got the same error.