# Building a simple render array and rendering it

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to render a render array. This render array will be configurable through a UI.

For some reason, I'm unable to render it.

I've isolated the issue so we can replicate it quickly.

Here's the render array:

```
$render_array = array(
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'h1',
  '#attributes' => array('class' => 'title'),
  'children' => array(
    array(
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => 'Link title',
      '#href' => 'Link URL',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => 'inner'),
    )
  )
);

$html = render($render_array);

debug($html);
```

The result of this is:

```
<h1 class="title" />
```

I tried many possibilities, tested multiple things... but it won't work.

I also searched the API and found [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/61491#comment-61491) and the example in the comment is pretty much the same as mine... but it won't work either.

Is there an easy why to build a complete HTML structure with a render array ?

I could use `'#theme' => 'link'` but it's not advised, see [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-theme-a-link-in-a-d7-render-array#comment76070_24698).

Anyone got a clue ?

Thanks!

Edit1: I opened [an issue on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2981632) which is a workaround to get this fixed.

Comment: I assume you have tested with a valid '#href', yes? Have you tested with #type => markup & #markup = 'Foooooooooo'?  If that works then it is your link which is invalid

Comment: Nothing is printed when the parent is '#type' => 'html_tag'. If you replace it with 'container', it works but you cannot change the HTML tag, it's automatically a div. I'm unable to find in the code what is the difference between the container and the html_tag component. It's so weird.

Comment: @PolDellaiera It starts in `system_element_info`, that defines the elements. For the `html_tag` type it uses [`theme_html_tag`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_html_tag/7.x) to render, and that function doesn't render children. There's a preprocess function in one of the comments that looks like it should fix the problem though: https://api.drupal.org/comment/49603#comment-49603. After implementing that you can lose the wrapping `children` element and put the links straight on the parent e.g. `0 => ['#type' => 'link', ...], 1 => ['#type' => 'link', ...]`

Comment: Yeah that I saw as well, but then where does [theme_container()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_container/7.x) render its children then ?
Regarding the preprocess, I saw it as well but I don't think this should be solved using a preprocess. I opened [an issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2981632), I hope to get good feedback.

Comment: The only relevant difference is that `theme_container` renders `$element['#children']`, but `theme_html_tag` doesn't. If `theme_html_tag` did render it, instead of rendering `$element['#value']`, all would be well. But from the docs and code it's a safe bet this element was intended for use in the `<head>`, not for general markup, and I imagine that's something like the reply you might get on drupal.org. They wouldn't be able to change it, it'd break existing implementations, so I think the best advice is going to be to use a preprocess. Happy to be proved wrong though!

Comment: This is indeed the conclusion that I came up with and why I created an issue on drupal.org to modify the 'container' element instead of 'html_tag'.

Comment: Nice, hope that gets in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79347/discussion-between-pol-dellaiera-and-clive).

Comment: In the end, I proposed a new patch for Drupal 7, this is a backport of what's done in Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2981726

Answer (score 0):

I believe "children" needs to have a "#" ... You could also try using #value instead of children

Comment: haha, I tried, trust me... it doesn't work.